# How to colour code a PCA plot based on the data frame cell names?

Tags: r, pca

```
data.matrix <- matrix(nrow=100, ncol=10)
colnames(data.matrix) <- c(
  paste("wt", 1:5, sep=""),
  paste("ko", 1:5, sep=""))
rownames(data.matrix) <- paste("gene", 1:100, sep="")
for (i in 1:100) {
  wt.values <- rpois(5, lambda=sample(x=10:1000, size=1))
  ko.values <- rpois(5, lambda=sample(x=10:1000, size=1))
 
  data.matrix[i,] <- c(wt.values, ko.values)
}
head(data.matrix)
dim(data.matrix)

pca <- prcomp(t(data.matrix), scale=TRUE) 

intall.packages("ggplot2")
library(ggplot2)
 
pca.data <- data.frame(Sample=rownames(pca$x),
  X=pca$x[,1],
  Y=pca$x[,2])
pca.data
 
ggplot(data=pca.data, aes(x=X, y=Y, label=Sample)) +
  geom_text() +
  xlab(paste("PC1 - ", pca.var.per[1], "%", sep="")) +
  ylab(paste("PC2 - ", pca.var.per[2], "%", sep="")) +
  theme_bw() +
  ggtitle("My PCA Graph")
```

The above code gives me this final pca plot:
[image]

How can change the wt and ko points into coloured dots? (ie. change all "wt" points to blue dots and all "ko" points to red dots)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** The question was changed after my initial answer, see the bottom for updated answer.

You can get the second character of `Sample` with `substr()`, and then pass that to `col`. Here is an example:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

example_data <- data.frame(
  Sample = c("A1.1", "H2.1", "F2.1", "B1.1", "C1.1", "S2.1", "J2.1", "K1.1"),
  X = rnorm(n = 8),
  Y = rnorm(n = 8)
)


example_data %>% 
  mutate(prop = substr(Sample, 2, 2)) %>% # Make a new column with the values
  ggplot(aes(x = X, y = Y, label = Sample, col = prop)) +
  geom_text() +
  xlab(paste("PC1 - ")) +
  xlab(paste("PC2 - ")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("1" = "blue", "2" = "red")) + # Assigns colour to values
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = "none") # Removes legend
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-06-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

With the edited question, here is how to get points instead of text. Simply swap out `geom_text()` for `geom_point()`.

```r
example_data %>% 
  mutate(prop = substr(Sample, 2, 2)) %>% # This is where the magic happens
  ggplot(aes(x = X, y = Y, label = Sample, col = prop)) +
  # geom_text() +
  geom_point() + # Will add points
  xlab(paste("PC1 - ")) +
  ylab(paste("PC2 - ")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("1" = "blue", "2" = "red")) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-06-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>